# C++: delete[][]ing multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c++

I was shocked to notice that the following code is working correctly on my machine, i.e. constructing and destroying all 25 objects of the two-dimensional array in the correct order.

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
  C() { std::cout << '+' << this << "\n"; }
  ~C() { std::cout << '-' << this << "\n"; }
};

typedef C T[5][5];

int main() {
  void *t = new T;
  delete (T *) t;
  return 0;
}
```

Is it indeed a valid way of allocating and deallocating multi-dimensional arrays according to the standard? Are operators `new` and `delete` actually required to introspect multi-dimensional array types recursively in this manner?

Comment: Are you shocked that this works if you just do `T t;`? The same 25 objects have to be constructed and destructed, right?

Comment: I have a feeling your compiler is optimizing away the new/delete

Comment: This is not a matrix. This is an array of 5 x 5 = 25 elements.

Comment: My compiler is not optimizing away the new/delete because it's actually printing 50 prints.

Comment: @jxh An array is just a pointer to the first element, correct? I think the confusion is that an array is allocated, but being correctly deallocated by delete, not delete[]. It should be undefined behavior but he could be getting lucky

Comment: @NoQ The compiler may remove new/delete if the program has the same behavior. It would just stack allocate the objects instead

Comment: The reason why i'm shocked is that i no longer understand the difference between `new` and `new[]` and i'm trying to figure out which one of these correspond to the "`new[][]`" presented above.

Comment: @NoQ you may still [edit] your question to clarify what it is you are really asking.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what i'm asking about: "Is it indeed a valid way of allocating and deallocating multi-dimensional arrays according to the standard?".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239446/315052

Comment: @BradyDean: The compiler may treat the `[5][5]` as syntactic sugar that is mostly enforced at compile time. Since what is being destructed by `delete` is a pointer to an array, the array deletion may have been silently applied.

Comment: @jxh That would make sense. It should be UB, at least according to cppreference. gcc is only giving me a warning about deleting void*

Comment: `delete (T *) t` is actually UB, that is not the type of `t`. `t` is actually `C (*)[5]`.

Comment: clang gives me the following warning: `'delete' applied to a pointer-to-array type 'T *' (aka 'C (*)[5][5]') treated as 'delete[]'`

Comment: Use `auto` instead of `void *`. Get rid of the cast in the call to `delete`.

Comment: ...and the type of the new-expression is indeed `C (*)[5]` in it.

Comment: @jxh thanks! I think i'm starting to understand this.

Comment: @DrewDormann incorrect; the type of the pointer being deleted must match the type returned by its `new`   (or a base class of, with virtual destructor)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: https://tio.run/##fY3NCoJAFIX3PsXBNoW4sKU/bXwFoUW1GMarDeiMOHeIEHv0pkladzlw4PDxXTlNqRyE7v1OaTm4llAqY3kmMZ58aCcZNZYI4WrsD1hguc1zaRyjLMF3Zb8dI7nquMC6ka//aPpD1yKK@DlRS12QN5fjLSRsSjNGofQm2YTCsQGjgqYHmmLbWhqICVxEq/dv2Q2itz490zyb2afhdSWTJMs@

Comment: @RemyLebeau: https://tio.run/##rZHBasMwDIbveQrRXbyFHLqjk@7SVyjs0JVgHKUzOLax5Y21ZI8@z/WgDAZhjAmBQPz6fiFJ5xqphTmmG2WkjgNCp2wgj2J6SLlGSbCFcwU5tsBu4QyBBs6ljQRdB/SswqWuoH4yqxbmonxfljbfpC9WDXAH1qEXZD0YfAUW1Al7gnD6Aen7MRrZ9wVUMB4pegOcT0JrK1keWmDvD/9Lv7IH1EgI7MvT/QLN@egRmVsEXvb9I3Juq4reHA445tft9veHnLmnDMEklCkvKsYikgWCTTn@ri29qz211ZzShxy1OIbUPKL31qcmb7KRdb1efwI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is not correct, because:

1. The subexpression of the `delete` operator does not have the correct type.
2. Since the allocated type is an array type, you must use the `delete[]` syntax.

The correct code would be:

```
// C and T as in the OP.

int main() {
    C (*t)[5] = new T; // or just: auto t = new T;
    delete [] t;
}
```

First, the type of `new T` is `C (*)[5]`, not `T*` (or `C*`, etc.)  [expr.new]/5:

> When the allocated object is an array (that is, the *noptr-new-declarator* syntax is used or the *new-type-id* or *type-id* denotes an array type), the *new-expression* yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array. [ Note: Both `new int` and `new int[10]` have type `int*` and the type of `new int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]` — end note ]

The same type must be used in the subexpression of `delete[]`, and since the allocated object is an array, the `delete[]` operator must be used. [expr.delete]/2:

> In a single-object delete expression, the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject representing a base class of such an object. If not, the behavior is undefined. In an array delete expression, the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array *new-expression*. If not, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: This means that the syntax of the *delete-expression* must match the type of the object allocated by `new`, not the syntax of the *new-expression*. — end note ]

In particular, if the pointer value resulting from your *new-expression* was cast to a different type such as `T*`, the pointer value of that type is not the pointer value which resulted from the *new-expression*.  Except as noted for deleting a single polymorphic class object, the type of pointer given to `delete` or `delete[]` needs to be the same as the type of the *new-expression*.

As far as initializing and destroying goes: No matter how an array object is created, initializing the array object involves initializing each element of that array. When you have an array of arrays, this applies recursively. So the expression `new T` creates and initializes one `C[5][5]` array object, which means initializing five `C[5]` objects, and each of those initializations means initializing five `C` objects (for a total of 25 `C` constructor calls).

And no matter how an array object was created, a valid way of destroying that array object involves destroying each element of that array, in reverse order.  So the `delete [] t;` statement destroys the entire array whose first element is `*t` - this means destroying all five elements of type `C[5]`, and each of those destructions means destroying five `C` objects (for a total of 25 `~C` destructor calls).

Note the compiler knows from the type of `t` that the elements of the array have type `C[5]`, but it doesn't specify the major size of the array. The same expression would be valid if `*t` were actually, for example, the first element of a `C[8][5]` array instead. Behind the scenes, many compilers will solve this issue by storing a count of array elements next to any array allocated by a *new-expression*, so that the later *delete-expression* can determine how many elements need to be destroyed.

Comment: One way to dynamically allocate one `T` would be to `new T[1]`. Still requires `delete[]` though.

Comment: @jxh `new T` also dynamically allocates one `T`. It's just that the _new-expression_ does not then have type `T*`.  `new T[1]` would have type `T*`, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: Yes, the asker seemed to want to get a `T *`.

Comment: One more thing to consider, smart pointers: https://tio.run/##fYzLCsIwEEX3/YpBN5VSQTeCfWz6C4ILFQnpqEGT1GSilFI/3Rir4M5hYODeM4c3TXrk3I@F4hdXI@RCWzLIZBn9MolSm7b0oXGcoIIugjAVxBPowFK9XHLtCPIc6CTs@44g2apRBv1APv6j6RftsyiitsEaD0G@2sx3YUMmFIFkQg2SQcgcaSAoPkbJzrh3Slwd5tXm/VTG80n2I2@BVHiH1SejqUGLFN8C03v/5IcLO1qfrtEYbXwapAVPktniBQ